# Jupyter-notebook failed to launch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I opened Anaconda Navigator with the command `"anaconda-navigator"` and tried to launch Jupyter and this huge list of errors appear. Please help me resolve this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Slamet\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\Slamet\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq.eventloop'
```

Comment: Please, check if you have installed python binding for zeromq.

Comment: @WiraAmbarita Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you use Windows or Linux? also, how did you install Anaconda ?